# No me muestra una vista en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, vistas, error404

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con CodeIgniter 3 en la que mi intención es crear una liga o competiciones de fútbol, la cual acabo de empezar.
El problema es que, aunque tengo la base de datos con dos partidos de prueba (bastante sobrio ya que solo tiene un ID, una descripción, fecha de creación y el slug), no soy capaz de acceder a la vista de los partidos por separado.
Tengo una vista que muestra todos los partidos de la base de datos por pantalla, recorriendo la tabla con un foreach, y eso funciona correctamente, pero cuando estoy creando la vista individual para cada partido, en la cual lo que hago es buscar en la base de datos el partido que tiene el mismo slug que le estoy pasando y me devuelva los datos, no funciona.
Adjunto los códigos relevantes.

El controlador de Partidos:

```
<?php
    class Partidos extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){
            
            $data['titulo'] = 'Ultimos Partidos';

            $data['partidos'] = $this->partido_modelo->get_partidos();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('partidos/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function view($slug = NULL){
            $data['partido'] = $this->partido_modelo->get_partidos($slug);

            if(empty($data['partido'])){
                show_404();
            }

            $data['titulo'] = $data['partido']['titulo'];

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('partidos/view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

    }
```

Como decía, la función index() funciona perfectamente, tanto en la vista como el controlador como el modelo. Donde me falla es en la función view() que me da error 404.

El código del modelo de Partidos:

```
<?php
    class Partido_modelo extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct(){
            $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_partidos($slug = FALSE){
            if($slug === FALSE){
                $query = $this->db->get('partidos');
                return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('partidos', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
    }
```

Vista index.php (la que muestra todos los partidos) [FUNCIONA BIEN]:

```
<h2><?=$titulo?></h2>
<?php foreach($partidos as $partido) :  ?>
    <div class="container">
    <h3><?php echo $partido['titulo']; ?></h3>
    <?php echo $partido['body']; ?><br>
    <small><span style="float:right" class="badge badge-secondary">Creado el: <?php echo $partido['creacion']; ?></span></small>
    <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo site_url('/partidos/'.$partido['slug']); ?>">Saber más</a></p>
</div>
    <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Vista view.php (la de cada partido por separado) [NO LLEGA A MOSTRAR ESTA VISTA]:

```
<h2><?php echo $partido['titulo']; ?></h2>
<div class="partido-body">
    <?php echo $partido['body']; ?>
</div>
```

Y por último el archivo routes.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['partidos/:(any)'] = 'partidos/view/$1';
$route['partidos'] = 'partidos/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'paginas/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'paginas/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Creo que está todo correcto, pero aun así no termino de encontrar que fallo sintáctico o que tipo de error tengo para no conseguir mostrar la vista view() y que no me aparezca la vista del partido por separado.

Por último adjunto capturas de la vista index.php y de la vista view.php de cada partido, en la cuales se aprecia que es capaz de sacar la información de la base de datos y que las URLs funcionan correctamente, pero aun así no es capaz de mostrar la vista por pantalla.

Vista index.php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista view.php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Partidos Base de Datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La declaración de la ruta esta mal, la forma correcta para declarar la rutas con parámetros debe ser de la siguiente forma:

```
$route['partidos/(:any)'] = 'partidos/view/$1';
```

Los 2 puntos debe ir dentro de los paréntesis especificando el tipo dato que se enviara.

Extraído de la documentación de [codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)